# The word '' is incorrectly spelled JasperReports XML

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, datasource

In Jaspersoft Studio, I have the following XML as data source for a new report:

```
 <Test>
    <a>a1</a>
    <a>a2</a>
    <a>a3</a>
    <a>a4</a>
    <row>
        <b>b1</b>
    </row>
    <row>
        <b> b2 </b>
    </row>
    <row>
        <b> b4 </b>
    </row>
    <row>
        <b> b5 </b>
    </row>
    <ratatata> </ratatata>
    <raw> </raw>
    <popopocd> </popopocd>
    <ruw> </ruw>
    <rew> </rew>
    <row> </row>
    <pow> </pow>
    <raraw> </raraw>
    <raw> </raw>
</Test>
```

and it gives me this error `The word '' is incorrectly spelled` the whole time.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an error in your XML source code, where you forgot to close the tag `<popopocd>`.  Here is the corrected XML:

```
<Test>
    <a>a1</a>
    <a>a2</a>
    <a>a3</a>
    <a>a4</a>
    <row>
        <b>b1</b>
    </row>
    <row>
        <b> b2 </b>
    </row>
    <row>
        <b> b4 </b>
    </row>
    <row>
        <b> b5 </b>
    </row>
    <ratatata> </ratatata>
    <raw> </raw>
    <popopocd> </popopocd> <!-- I closed the tag here for you -->
    <ruw> </ruw>
    <rew> </rew>
    <row> </row>
    <pow> </pow>
    <raraw> </raraw>
    <raw> </raw>
</Test>
```

Please try generating the report again and let us know if this fixed your problem.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. I still have the same problem. It happens with all the tags that are not "row" or "raw" as you can see in the image :(

Comment: Please look into XML namespaces.  You may need to provide a namespace for the tags which are causing problems http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: forgive me for making you lose time. It seems there is some kind of spell check activated on the Jasper Studio and it checks the tag names with the dictionary >_<
 http://snag.gy/arn60.jpg